# Time variation in coefficients

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, least-squares, kalman-filter

Given $x_t, y_t$ ($t=1,\ldots,240$), I want to estimate $y_t = \alpha_t + \beta_t x_t$ and test $H_0: \alpha_1=\ldots=\alpha_T=0$. It is crucial to allow for time variation in the regression coefficients.

For instance, $x_t$ is the monthly market return in excess of the riskfree rate, and $y_t$ are excess returns of a stock portfolio. I consider to use one of the following two methods.

- **Kalman filter** This requires a parametric model for the processes of $\alpha_t$ and $\beta_t$. Is normality for the coëfficient processes ok?
- **Feasible GLS** Estimate for $s = 60,\ldots,240$ the overlapping rolling estimation windows
  $$
  \left[\begin{array}\\ y_{s-59}\\ \vdots\\ y_{s}\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}\\ 1\\ \vdots\\ 1\\ \end{array} \right] \alpha_s + \left[\begin{array}\\ x_{s-59}'\\ \vdots\\ x_s'\\ \end{array} \right] \beta_s + \left[\begin{array}\\ e_{s,s-59}\\ \vdots\\ e_{s,s}\\ \end{array} \right]
  $$
  Since the error terms are dependent for the same $y_t$ in different windows ending at, say $s1$ and $s2$, define $\sigma_{s_1s_2}:=Cov(\varepsilon_{s1,t},\varepsilon_{s2,t})$ for all common $t$ in the two regression windows. Further, the variance $\sigma_{t,t}:=Cov(\varepsilon_{s,t},\varepsilon_{s,t})$ is allowed to be nonzero and identical for all regression windows $s$. All other covariance terms are supposed to be zero. First, the covariance matrix is estimated with residuals from OLS estimates. Second, the GLS estimator is used with this covariance matrix.

Remarkably, I could not find papers in the finance literature which compare the two methods. Is either of the two methods preferred? Or do better methods exist?
Thanks in advance.